# Cycles checkerboard pattern only on GPU

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, smoke-simulation, gpu

I am trying to render a short smoke scene using cycles. Everything works fine (even if slowly) when I am using the CPU, as shwon below.

[image: Image without any issues, rendered on CPU.]

However, when I try using my GPU, it looks like some parts of the smoke are missing, resulting in a weird checkerboard pattern.

[image: Botched image, rendered on GPU]

Any ideas how to fix this issue? Rendering the animation is extremely slow if I can only use the CPU.

My specs are:

Blender: 2.93

OS: Windows 10

CPU: Ryzen 5 2600

GPU: AMD RX 580 4GB

Driver: 21.5.1

The blender file can be downloaded [here](https://ufile.io/r27xuhbn)

Comment: Two things. 

1. Changing the driver to the current AMD Radeon Pro driver did not make a difference.
2. Going into Options > System > OpenCL and unticking the CPU removed the checkerboard pattern, but now only a [small corner of the smoke is rendered](https://ibb.co/YkTDG5v)